# How to Manage Escapes for an AWK statement with Full Path Returns From a FOR Loop

Tags: awk, aix

I have a loop that to scan for key error message in a same name file in different paths - I use this FOR loop to get all the files

```
for i in /usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/logs/server42c_*/SystemOut.log
do
  echo  $i  
done
```

and it needs to put the $i value into this awk statement with the escape slash

```
currentcount=`awk '$0 ~ /Reason code "68"/' \/usr\/IBM\/WebSphere\/AppServer\/profiles\/AppSrv01\/logs\/server42c_ABC\/SystemOut.log|wc -l`
```

how would you edit in these escape slashes if they are not returned in the $i ?  That is the value will be returned without slashes.

Comment: can you share the SystemOut.log file or some lines of it! please!

Comment: Why do you want to escape the slashes? `for i in /path*/log; do current_count=$(grep -Fc 'Reason code "68"' "$i"); done`. There's also `grep -Fc 'Reason code "68"' /path*/log` to list the count for each file. Both are POSIX and should work on AIX.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to escape the slashes in order to use the variable as a filename for your awk statement:

```sh
for logfile in /usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/logs/server42c_*/SystemOut.log
do
  currentcount=$(awk '$0 ~ /Reason code "68"/' "$logfile" | wc -l)
done
```

I've made three changes:

- renamed the variable `i` to `logfile` to be clearer about its purpose
- double-quoted the variable when I used it so that any wildcards or characters from $IFS will not cause surprises after variable expansion
- changed your backticks to the newer `$( ... )` syntax; they accomplish the same task